# Incandescent Bulb replaced by CFL

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling, replacement, light-bulb

In an enclosed ceiling fixture 50+ years old, using incandescent 60 watt bulbs max, can you use a 100 watt CFL bulb?

Comment: I do not know of any CFL bulbs that use 100w.  There are 13 or 15w CFL bulbs that put out the light of a 100w incandescent bulb.  As long as the power use of the bulb is less than 60w max, you should be good.  LEDs use even less.  The problem is the newer type bulbs do not like heat, so an enclose non-ventilated space is not good for them.

Comment: I can't answer because I haven't seen a CFL  bulb this decade.  Jump into the new age LEDs you will be happier.

Comment: @RMDman  Not if you have an easy bake oven.

Comment: Do they still make Easy Bake Ovens?

Comment: @crip659 Marketing nonsense strikes again - CFLs and LED bulbs are commonly marketed by the incandescent equivalent power in big text, with the real power consumption not so obvious

Comment: @ChrisH  I meant 'use' as consuming/using 100w of power, not being like a 100w of light.  Think the big/powerful(common household) CFLs use only about 23/25w

Comment: @crip659 I know you meant it correctly. I'm not sure the OP did given how common the misuse is. They probably didn't, given the values in your last comment (which I'd say are even a touch high)

Comment: the easy way to tell if any bulb technology is compatible with a fixture is to run it for 10 mins and check temp; (aside from tungsten) it should be cool enough to unscrew. Repeat after 20 and 30 mins. If you can unscrew it, or almost unscrew it bare-handed after 30 mins, it's safe.

Answer (score 3):

There's two reasons that fixtures will have wattage limits:

- Heat - this was common for older fixtures. You limited the wattage to keep it from getting too hot in the fixture or wiring. CFL and LED bulbs are less happy at high temperatures, so you want to limit older fixtures to a fraction of their original rating, i.e. perhaps 60W rated fixtures are good for a 20W modern bulb.
- Glare - sometimes the design of the fixture means it's uncomfortable to look at a fixture if there's too much light coming out of it. This is more of a big deal now that you can put very bright LED and CFL bulbs in place of older incandescent bulbs at a given wattage. This is rare but it happens. A common example is open chandeliers, which may specify 25w bulbs even though the wiring and heat tolerance could work for 40w bulbs.

Ideally you want to look at **lumens** rather than watts when determining how big a bulb you can use nowadays. Watts are used on the front of packages because they're very familiar to those of us who were buying lightbulbs for years. An incandescent bulb of 40 watts puts out about 560 lumens; 60 watts is 800 lumens, and 100 watts is 1600 lumens. Notice that it's not a linear relationship. LED and CFL bulb makers take advantage of this confusion to stretch their numbers - you'll see bulbs marked as '60W Equivalent' when they're 650 lumens, or '100W equivalent' at 1300 lumens.

So what are you supposed to do? First, start ignoring watts for brightness, shop by lumens instead. Learn how many lumens you like for given scenarios, and buy bulbs to suit. Keep an eye on fixtures for their watt rating, but so long as you stay below about a third of the rating I would expect no issues with heat at all. That may seem conservative, but LED bulbs are less tolerant of heat than incandescent bulbs, and running them too hot leads to a short lifespan. Some LED bulbs are not even rated for enclosed fixture usage, though that tends to be rare nowadays in all but the cheapest bulbs.

This is how I've ended up with '75W' and '100W' equivalent bulbs where I used to have 60W, and '40W' equivalent bulbs where I used to have 60W ones. In some places I'm even running '150W' equivalent bulbs where I used to have a 60W, with a dimmer so I can get a huge range of controllable light level. LEDs have opened things wide with possibility. Enjoy it!

Comment: In everything I've come across, the stated limit has been due to heat.  Glare depends on how you use it as well as the shape of the fitting.  This is a problem with floor-standing halogen uplighters if you're tall enough to see over the rim to their 150-300W bulbs

Comment: An example where glare is a factor is chandeliers with exposed bulbs. They will sometimes spec 25w max even though the wiring is plenty big enough for 40w bulbs and heat is not much of a concern. With LEDs you could replace those typically 150 lumen chandelier bulbs with 800 lumen equivalents pretty easily, but it would be a bad idea unless you light looking at bright points of light.