# I have matching 3-way, 100 W max table lamps. I need 150 W max for my eyes. My new 150 W 3-way bulbs flicker. Can I upgrade my lamps to use 150W?

Tags: light-fixture

I have matching 3-way, 100 W max table lamps. I need 150 W to see. My new 150 W 3-way bulbs flicker. Can lamps upgrade to 150W?

Comment: No, you don't need 150W to see. You need 150W of incandescent light bulbs worth of **lumens** to see. Quick search says that's around 2600 lumens. So now you need to search for an LED bulb that produces around 2600 lumens, and spend extra for a high-quality bulb to take care of the flicker.

Comment: The wattage rating on lamp fixtures is the maximum for non LED bulbs.  Going above can lead to bad stuff happening like fire.  Either get fixtures rated higher or change to LEDs and save money.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incandescent Bulb replaced by CFL](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/273673/incandescent-bulb-replaced-by-cfl)

Comment: Is this a touch lamp? A lamp wouldn't cause flicker, so there's no way to "upgrade" them. It's all about the bulbs.

Answer (score 3):

Watts is the amount of **heat** a light bulb makes. Fixtures have thermal limits that must be followed to avoid starting a fire.

Now, here's a new concept for you.  This has nothing to do with how much **light** the bulb makes. Lights are measured in **lumens**. (that's new to you). LEDs are ridiculously efficient; 10 times as efficient as incandescents in some cases.  More lumens less watts.

**If you don't like LEDs because of ugly color, you've been looking at cheap LEDs. Stop.** Good ones last forever, so make your investment count.

But back when incandescent was the only light, people used to say "watts" when they really meant brightness.  *That no longer works.*   To help people buy LED lights, many of them are labeled with "watt equivalents" and that information is a lie (they're falsifying the data) and you should ignore it.

Go by "Lumens" for brightness and "Watts" for power usage.

An old "100 watt" incandescent is 1600 lumens.

I think you are looking for about 2500 lumens.

LEDs give plenty of light for just a few watts. So staying under 100 watts isn't a problem.

However finding very large single LEDs is sometimes hard.  Feel free to change the fixture to one with multiple bulbs. Fixtures are cheap. Choose an open-sided fixture - one that is sealed is very bad for LEDs because they need ventilation to keep cool.

I have a GE Relax "50/150/100" (remember, that's a lie) LED bulb that I am extremely happy with. The color is wonderful.  It has the brightest position in the middle, so if you screw it into a non-3-way fixture, you get the max brightness. Clever!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get much more light out of an old lamp is to buy LED bulbs.   As long as the lamp is vented (open) on top you can replace, for example, a 100W incandescent bulb with a 60W *actual* 3000K LED bulb, which will produce light somewhat similar to a 500W halogen bulb.

The quality and color of the light will vary by manufacturer.  But they are cheap so you can experiment.

You can go up to the rating of the lamp in *actual* wattage (not equivalent wattage).  These high-watt LED bulbs do produce a lot of heat.  Not as much as incandescents, but you have to put them in open fixtures or they will overheat and fail.

You have to read the light bulb specs very carefully.  Especially in the 40 to 100 watt range, you get some bulbs that are advertised in equivalent watts, others in actual watts, and you have to look carefully to see what you're getting.  The most important thing to compare is the lumen output and color.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't upgrade or change them without losing the UL approval. The 100 watt maximum is based on the amount of heat the bulb will generate, how much heat the wires can safely tolerate in the socket and also on how much heat the lamp shade can safely tolerate. Changing to 150 watt bulbs could be dangerous and could cause a fire. You might want to try some of the different LEDs on the market that are equivalent to 150 watt bulbs.